# Project added to solution in source control but can't be seen on another PC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've been playing around with Team Foundation Server's source control through Visual Studio 2012. I've added a new project and committed it into source control, however on another PC, when we pull the latest version, the project doesn't show.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

Which you have done, “**commit**” into source control only works on the local dev machine. You must use **sync** , then to share your code in the server to make sure other members or other computer  can get it.

[image]

Or you can directly use the **Commit and Push** button to commit the changes to your local repo then push your changes to server.

[image]